# Perpendicular lines on sloped lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to make a diagram in TikZ which is supposed to illustrate the triangle you construct when constructing a 60 degree angle. I'm having some troubles, mainly concerning the title of the question, that is: identical ticks on the triangle lines. An MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0]
        \node (origo) at (0,0) {} ;
        \draw (-0.5,0)--(3,0) ;
        \filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=green!50!black]
        (0,0)--+(5em,0em) arc (0:60:5em) node[name=top,inner sep=0]{} -- cycle; % green arc
        \draw (0,0)--+(5em,0em) node[name=base]{} arc (-5:100:5em) ; % large arc
        \draw[red] (origo.center)--node[midway,name=a]{}(base.center)--node[midway,name=b]{}(top.center)node[midway,name=c]{}--cycle ;
        \draw (5em,0) arc[start angle=115, end angle=125,radius=5em] ; % triangle top point arc
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

A couple of questions follows (no surprise, eh?)

1. Usually when illustrating that a triangle has equally long sides, you "tick" each side. How can I do this? I started out by defining nodes halfway along the triangle sides, but got stuck on the `cycle` path, and don't really know how to create perpendicular, small ticks in those nodes. This is my main question, thus the question title.
2. The large arc is an attempt to illustrate how the compass often looks, and I would like it to begin a few degrees lower than zero. However, `arc (-5:100:5em)` doesn't extend the arc below, it just transforms it. As the `arc` operation yields `(start angle):(end angle):(radius)` I thought this was the way to go...
3. I expected the small arc at the lower right to show up at the top of the triangle. How can I move it up there?

I suspect that both question 2 and 3 originates from the same problem: that I don't get a grasp about the `arc` operation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *definitely* a job for `tkz-euclide`, it's perfect for stuff like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Define the first point
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}

% Define the second and third point relative to the first
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](0:4){B}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](60:4){C}

% Draw the line segments between the points
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)

% Draw the tick marks
\tkzMarkSegments[mark=|,color=red](A,B A,C B,C)

% Draw the arc from B to C around A, with an extra 5° past the start and finish
\tkzDrawArc[color=red,style=solid, delta=5](A,B)(C)

% Draw the points
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```